# How to understand the identity atlas, containing a single chart $U \rightarrow U$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

From the textbook: Introduction to Differential Topology by TH. Brocker and K. Janich.

I'm trying to understand the identity atlas $\{ \textrm{Id}_U\}$.

Let's first look at how a manifold is defined:

> Definition 1.1: An n-dimensional topological manifold $M^n$ is a Hausdorff topological space with a countable basis for the topology, which is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, looking at this Identity Atlas from example 1.5a:

> 1.5a: If $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open subset, then the atlas ${\textrm{Id}_U}$, which only contains a single chart Id: $U \rightarrow U$ defines a differentiable atlas.

This confuses me, because I don't see how the dimensions can be correct. This could be key to my misconception, but I assume that a 2-manifold (which is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$) is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Therefore $n=2$ here. However, I do not understand how this identity map is possible from $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ as the authors say $U \rightarrow U$ meaning that both spaces are the same. I suspect that the fact that I assume we embed the manifold in $n+1$ is wrong as it is not specified in the book, I would appreciate clarification.

Comment: It's an atlas for $U$ as a manifold.

Comment: A $2$-manifold is not *"a surface in $\mathbb R^3$".* Some $2$-manifolds can be [embedded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#:~:text=In%20general%20topology%2C%20an%20embedding,the%20subspace%20topology%20inherited%20from%20) in $\mathbb R^3$. Some cannot. Some can even be embedded in $\mathbb R^2$, including in particular any one of them that is already an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: As Randall states, $\{Id_{U}\}$ is not an atlas for the space that you have embedded your surface in. It is only an atlas for your submanifold $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ which will be trivially homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{dim(U)}$.

Comment: There is no embedding. The second quote does not mention any embedding, so there is no reason to expect one. Here, the manifold is $M = U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and the coordinate map is $\phi: U \rightarrow M$, where $\phi$ is the identity map.

Comment: Where are you getting $\mathbb{R}^3$ from? It isn't mentioned in any of the quotes you provided and just randomly appears in your example.

Comment: @bmitc Yeah it's a misconception about manifolds I have due to my background (not math). I had assumed surfaces were 2-manifolds embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and that 2-manifolds, in general, were embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$